# Weight in Shopping cart is showing not updated value - Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I'm showing in my shopping cart the weight per item using: `$_item->getProduct()->getWeight()`, however, it shows the original product weight and not what was set after configurations of the item.

For example: Product A has the weight set as 10lb but it has some custom options in which increments the weight based on user choice, but when go to shopping cart it shows only 10lbs, even though that the summary freight calculations is getting the right weight.

Is there any code to show the real weight in the shopping cart?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the right code: `$_item->getWeight();`. My fault. Sorry.

That way shows properly the weight.